# How to find the intersection of 3 groups with pandas?

Tags: pandas, intersection

I managed to find the intersection using numpy.intersect1d() however I am unable to do this with 3 fields.

I have a 3 groups, and I want to make a 3-circle venn diagram, but I'm not sure how to do it with 3 groups. Any tips is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What result do you need? A ∩ B ∩ C? Or also the pairwise intersections (A ∩ B) \ C, (B ∩ C) \ A, and (C ∩ A) \ B?

Comment: The latter for the long run

Comment: my current solution is to make flags and filter and count, but i'm wondering if there is another way of doing so that's less clunky.

Comment: Intersection of multiple arrays can be efficiently computed with `functools.reduce(np.intersect1d, (A, B, C))`. To compute the other sets, use something like `np.setdiff1d(np.intersect1d(A, B), C)`. I'm not sure there is a less clunky way.

Comment: Thank you Igor, i'll compare with my current technique. appreciate the help!